# Dope Sheet has red lines

Tags: animation, dopesheet

[image]

I've searched for other answers but no luck yet, and it is for sure that i have kept the naming consistent, but still i got the problem when i restart my project. and i've tried other's python code but it would just return "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bones' ". Renaming the bone would just result in nothing, but the description's name changed too.

Comment: this happens if you rename bones after you keyframed them. Check your bone names. If you want a specific answer, pls provide blend file so that we can check it out. thx.